# Find $P(1)$ when $P$ be a monic polynomial with real coefficients and $P(0) = -1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P$ be a monic polynomial with real coefficients and $P(0) = -1$. Assume that $P$ has no roots in the open unit disk $D$. Find $P(1)$.

---

totally stuck on it.can any one help me please. I guess maximum modulus theorem may be helpful but how?

Comment: There is no chance to find $P(1)$ - you don't know enough about $P$. Just consider $P(z) = cz-1$, for $c>1$: they all satisfy the assumptions!

Comment: @Feanor: But then $1/c < 1$ would be a root in the unit disk?

Comment: I meant $0 < c < 1$. Only now did I realise the polynomial is supposed to be monic, so this was nonsense anyway.

Comment: please anyone tell me how should I proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$ be all the roots of $P$, counting multiplicities, so that $P$ takes the form:
$$ P(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i) $$
We have $(-1)^n\prod{z_i} = -1$ by evaluating at $0$. On the other hand, we have $|z_i| \geq 1$, because there are no roots in the open unit disk. This is only possible when $|z_i| = 1$!

Finally, because $P$ has real coefficients, the roots are either real or come in pairs with their conjugates. Because the only real numbers $t$ with $|t| =1$ are $+1$ and $-1$, we can (wlog) write $P(z) = (z-1)^a (z+1)^b Q(z)$, where roots of $Q$ are $z_1, \bar{z}_1, \dots, z_m, \bar{z}_m$ so that:
$$ Q(z) = \prod_{i=1}^m (z-z_i)(z-\bar{z}_i) =  \prod_{i=1}^m (z^2-2z\Re z_i + 1)$$
(Honestly, this would require some rearranging/renaming)
Clearly, $Q(0) = 1$, so $-1=P(0)=(-1)^a$, and thus $a$ has to be odd. In particular, $a$ is non-zero. But this means that $1$ is a root of $P$: $P(1) = 0$.